# how do i separate certain separate things in a string

Tags: python

I have a string that I want to separate into certain portions.

```
triangle = (input("Please input the dimensions of a triangle: "))

def comma(tri):

    comma = triangle.find(",")
    comma2 = triangle.find(",")
    side1 = (triangle[0:comma])
    side2 = (triangle[comma+1:comma2])
    side3 = (triangle[comma2:])
    return side1, side2, side3
print (comma(triangle))
```

I want to make something that tells you what kind of triangle it is by inputting the side measurements. I was wondering how to separate the measurements from the input without using split.

Comment: Why don't you want to use split? Is this homework? If so please read [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/4518341) and [ask] more generally.

Comment: "find" can take a start index to search. Without it the search always starts at beginning of the string.

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research? Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service. See: [ask], [help/on-topic], https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users.

Answer (score 0):

Taking input this way will be very troublesome. There are many ways a user will input dimensions. Instead, just ask the user for input 3 times. Then just pass all 3 variables to a function.

```py
side1 = (input("Please input the first dimension of a triangle: "))
side2 = (input("Please input the second dimension of a triangle: "))
side3 = (input("Please input the third dimension of a triangle: "))
```